# Any way to make "const {user, userId} = this.state" work if user references username and userId references id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

for example

```
 state = { 
      "username": "abc",
      "id": "1",
 } 


 const {username, id} = this.state
```

the above code would work and get the values

is there a way to make it so below would also work

```
const {user, userId} = this.state
```

That is, get the same values as username, id but with different names. Any way to tell javascript that user means username and userId means id?

Comment: I don't know if you are referring to alias, if so, you can do it like this `const {username:user, id: userId} = this.state;` then you can use `user` and `userId` in your code

Comment: See **[THIS](https://codeburst.io/renaming-destructured-variables-in-es6-807549754972)** guide from codeburst. It explains what are you looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this if you just want to use different names:

```
const {username: user, id: userId} = this.state
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it like this:

```
const {username: user, id: userId} = this.state
```

Great docs here https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment

Comment: oops I think I was the 3rd person to give you the same answer. Sorry for the redundancy

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to new variable names:

```
const o = {p: 42, q: true};
const {p: foo, q: bar} = o;
 
console.log(foo); // 42 
console.log(bar); // true
```

More information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment